# How to fix ValueError: Invalid format specifier

Tags: python-3.x, variables

Here is my variable. But when I run the code, got an error.

Input:

```
first_heading = 'This is my heading'
heading = f'<!-- wp:generateblocks/container {"uniqueId":"84f02903","isDynamic":true,"blockVersion":2} --><!-- wp:generateblocks/headline {"uniqueId":"624f151c","element":"h3"} --><h3 class="gb-headline gb-headline-624f151c gb-headline-text">{first_heading}</h3><!-- /wp:generateblocks/headline --><!-- /wp:generateblocks/container -->'
```

Error Output:

```
    heading = f'<!-- wp:generateblocks/container {"uniqueId":"84f02903","isDynamic":true,"blockVersion":2} --><!-- wp:generateblocks/headline {"uniqueId":"624f151c","element":"h3"} --><h3 class="gb-headline gb-headline-624f151c gb-headline-text">{first_heading}</h3><!-- /wp:generateblocks/headline --><!-- /wp:generateblocks/container -->'ValueError: Invalid format specifier
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have curly braces in your f-string template which have special meaning. Right there at the beginning: `container {"uniqueId":`

Comment: Got it, Thank you.